# How to check if an x86 PTE is valid or not in Linux?

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, x86-64, page-tables

I am writing a kernel module which `kmalloc` some pages and dump the its related Page table entries.
But I found following `pmd_t`, whose value is 0x4a726573614c5f72, which is an invalid entry.

```
PMD(V: 0x000000003cfdb3cf P: 0x3c00000b8) = 0x4a726573614c5f72
```

The `pmd_present(*pmd)` returns non-zero, means true, which cause kernel panic when get pte from above pmd.

Here is the code to print out above,

```
if (pmd && pmd_present(*pmd)) {
      printk(" PMD(V: 0x%p P: 0x%llx) = 0x%llx\n",
 (void *)pmd, virt_to_phys(pmd), (uint64_t)pmd_val(*pmd));
}
```

So how to check if such an entry is valid or not in Linux kernel, is there any PGD/PUD/PMD/PTE functions for that?

Comment: *How* exactly are you dumping those entries?

Comment: Since the memory is allocated from kernel by calling kmalloc(); so I dumped the page table entries for the allocated memory by walking through kernel page table tree rooted from init_top_pgt, called functions like pgd_offset(), pud_offset(), pmd_offset(), pmd_val(), but I met an invalid PMD entry listed above, I am wondering if there is a way to know if the PMD is valid or not.

Comment: I'm asking you for the exact code, down to the `printk` statement, as we need that to understand if there is anything wrong. Post it editing your question.

Comment: I updated the question with my code to print out PMD entry.  Based on the pmd_present(*pmd), I am wondering how to know if a page in page table entry is really present in memory, 'P' bit is enough or not?